# How to call a a function with no input and output in golan main function?

Tags: go

I have a simple `main.go` file as follows:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func init() {
    fmt.Println("init!")
}

func main() {
    // init()
    fmt.Println("main")
}
```

When I run this program I see the following output!

```
init
main
```

I'm getting totally confused! I guess both functions with `func()` signature get run as entry points. But, more interestingly, I can't make a call to `init` function in `main`!

Can anyone please explain me what's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 7):

`init` is a [special name for a function that initializes a package](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_initialization). It's called automatically, and the spec mentions "init functions cannot be referred to from anywhere in a program". You should use any other name.